# Preorder to postorder in tree

Tags: algorithm

I have a question i want to create postorder from inorder and preorder, but i don't wana use reconstruction of tree, i want only recursive do this. I code this, and at this moment, i have a part of, right side of tree in preorder( First char in preorder is root, i find this in inorder, and i have left and right side, i recurency translate to right side), but i have a problem with left side of tree. I don't have no idea to do this. Can someone give me some of suggestion or code ? Please help :)

Comment: oh i forgot, i have preorder and inorder from two String ;)

Comment: An example would probably be helpful.

Comment: Hm i show example and my code :

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String a(String pre, String in, int start, int end) {
            char c = pre.charAt(start); //first char in preorder is root
            int ix = find(pre, in, c); // if we find this char in inorder translation we know where is left and right side of tree
            stack += c;
            if (start == 0 && flaga == true) {
                left = pre.substring(1, ix + 1);
                right = pre.substring(ix + 1, end);
                flaga = false;
                return a(right, in, 0, end);
            }
            String reverse = new StringBuffer(stos).reverse().toString();
    //stack to see
//        System.out.println("STACK " + stos);
            if (start < right.length()-1) {
                return a(right, in, start + 1, end - 1);
            }
            return ""; 
     }
    public static int find(String a, String b, char c) {
        int b_l = b.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < b_l; ++i)
            if (b.charAt(i) == c)
                return i;
        return -1;
```

First Test :
String pre = "FBADCEGIH";
String inorder = "ABCDEFGHI";
ANswer should be : //A, C, E, D, B, H, I, G, F
My problem is with left side of tree, i don't have any idea to do this correct, and i'm not sure my code work for all situation of preorder and inorder.